# How to connect angularjs $http.get with spring's @GetMapping

Tags: angularjs, spring

```
    $scope.getProjectDetails = function(theId){
       $http.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/project', {params: {theId}})
          .then(function(response){
             $scope.project = response.data;
          });
       }
```

this one generetes:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/editor-application/api/project?theId=1 404
```

and spring rest wants:

```
http://localhost:8080/editor-application/api/project/1
```

controller:

```
@GetMapping("/project/{theId}")    
public Project getProject(@PathVariable int theId) {

return editorService.getProject(theId);
}
```

how to make them speak with each other?

Comment: you can use strings concatenation.

Comment: I thought `@GetMapping("/project?theId={theId}")` will work but it doesn't.

Comment: you should replace this line `$http.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/project', {params: {theId}})` with `$http.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/project/' + theId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send a variable as a get parameter but in the back-end you are expecting it as a path variable. There can be two solutions to handle this:

1. Modify the Spring controller to accept the request parameter:

```
@GetMapping("/project")    
public Project getProject(@RequestParam int theId) {
    ...
}
```

There are no modifications needed for the AngularJS code.

2. Modify the `$http` request to send the variable as a path variable.

```
$http.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/project/' + theId)
    .then(function(response){
        ...
    });
```

In this case the controller does not need any modifications.